# Create a working copy on the same svn server

Tags: svn

I have a development made under svn revision control located in the local folder 
`/myCompany/myProject/`.

I would like to make a working copy into the local folder `/home/me/myProject`.

What are the command to create the working copy.  I have tried

```
me:/home/me/myProject$ svn checkout file:///mycompany/myProject/
svn: Unable to open ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///mycompany/myProject/'
```

I would like to create a svn repository with the current version as first revision, using "**dayly** commits".  Then I would like to merge last my working copy revision into the company's project latest revision, using "**feature** commits".

My fellow programmers do not like to branch but I would like to commit only full and debugged feature into the company's svn repository, keeping my stupids type mistakes and other intermediates failures in my own.  I hope a better confidence in my code by me fellow programmers.

I can stand I am at a each moment the lone programmer of the project.

How can I achieve such thing?  What commands should I use for each of local copy creation, daily commit, feature commit, local copy destruction?

Comment: Let's ignore if your approach is a good idea for now... What is `/mycompany`, is that really a local folder? Or is that a mounted share? Could you list its content? I ask because using a file based protocol to access a repository in a multi user environment is, well, questionable.

Comment: @arkascha Yes, it is a local folder

Comment: Well, why is it questionable?

Comment: Because it means that multiple write operations might access it in parallel in a multi user environment which will lead to data corruption in a file based access.

Comment: So I should use http://localhost/godknowswhat/myCompany/myProject ?

Comment: But I think that if data corruption occurs, that would not hurt me, since I have a working copy.  In addition, I am not responsible for svn, if svn do fail, I do not care...

Comment: Em, we are talking about data corruption _inside the svn repository_! You may not be responsible for the repository, but certainly you are part of the team in your company? I hope you do not work _against_ each other at that place?!?

Comment: Anyways, that is not the point of this question. I still do not understand the error message. What happens if you specify a target folder? `svn checkout /mycompany/myProject/ ./myCheckout`

Comment: If I use tty to enter svn checkout /mycompany/myProject/ , the I get in stout /mycompany/myProject/: unknown commands.

Comment: Sure, you wrote that in your question. Please take another look at my last comment. I suggested to additionally specify a target folder in the command. Any difference?

Comment: Yes, thank you, it is but I get a new unexpected message  `svn: unable to open an ra_local session`.

Comment: Sure you used three (3!) slashes after the `file` as I wrote?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50968/discussion-between-muy-belgium-and-arkascha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sorting things out in a lengthy exchange we learned that the correct command must be:

```
svn checkout file:///svn/myProject
```

One other thing: looking at your motivation I really suggest you should take a look at using `git` as a frontend repository for your svn based company repository. Things get a little more complex, but there are helper utilities for this. This difference is that you can do real commits to your private local environment and maintain separate branches which is not possible with the checkout approach you currently try.

Answer (score 1):

> My fellow programmers do not like to branch but I would like to commit only full and debugged feature into the company's svn repository, keeping my stupids type mistakes and other intermediates failures in my own. I hope a better confidence in my code by me fellow programmers.

Look at [git-svn](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) which will allow you to checkout your Subversion project as a local Git repository. Then, you can make your *checkpoint* commits until you are ready to commit your code. It's way easier than setting up your own Subversion repo, and trying to keep what you're doing in sync with your fellow developers

However, a word of caution: Programming is sloppy and messy work. You'll have bugs. You'll make mistakes. I don't know what language you're developing in, but you can always do a local build to verify your work before committing your changes. This way, you can at least make sure your changes don't prevent other developers from doing their work.

I tell developers to take *small bites*. That is, do small code changes and not grandiose changes. Don't pretend you're God and can create entire programs out of the void with mere thought.

For example, you're implementing a new feature that depends upon a new class. Work on the class, and write some tests. You can commit your initial class, and after you work on each method. You can then work on the feature bit-by-bit filling out the new feature with each change.

Keeping your code hidden until you finish is not a good way to learn and to become a better developer. I encourage developers to commit their changes, and share their code. Ask other developers for advise and what they think. This is how you learn.

If in the end, you don't want to use `git-svn` and you really, really want your own private work area, make your own branch. Not a feature branch, but a private branch for your own work. You can create the branch, do your work, reintegrate it back into the main workflow, then delete it. Rinse and Repeat. Subversion handles merges pretty well.